# How can I format a USB stick that's falsely marked as read-only?

Tags: usb, disk-utility

I was trying to create a bootable disk with Windows on it through bootcamp, but something went wrong during the installation. Now I have a read-only USB stick with corrupt files I'd like to fix. My USB stick doesn't have a read-only feature. Is there anything  I can do to force a reformat?

[image]

Comment: If it happened as a result of a write error, then the chances are the USB key's firmware has locked it. There is no way to unlock if that was the case. Get existing data off it & bin it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to partition the disk first.

If fails then by using Vendor and Product IDs of you flash drive find manufacturers' utility to perform low-level format. You will need Windows for that.